# Adding new customer from backend not inserting store id

Tags: magento, authentication, admin

I am using magento 1.7.0.2. I am having issue regarding store id. When I add new customer from the frontend by sign up, it adds the store id in the "Customer Entity" table. However, when I try to manually add a customer using the backend inserts "0" rather than the 'store id' in the "Customer Entity" table.
How can I get the store id of the customer when adding a customer by admin?
How to set option in backend to insert store id manually in "Customer Entity" table via backend? 
Is it required to set new field 'select store'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple.
go to /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
and just before //send welcome email part

```
// Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_customer_prepare_save', array(
//                    'customer'  => $customer,
//                    'request'   => $this->getRequest()
//                ));
```

And put following code there.

```
$storeId = $customer->getSendemailStoreId();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId);
$customer->save();
```

That's it now you can choose store from backend and will also be inserted in to customer_entity table.

solution find from [phprocks](http://phprocks.letsnurture.com/)